# How can I use x:Static with x:String

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want something like:

```
<Picker>
     <Picker.Items>
         <x:String>{x:Static local:SomeClass.ConstText}</x:String>
     </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mjwills I just get a string "{x:Static local:SomeClass.ConstText}" showing in my picker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `x:Static` is a markup extension, you can use it either through [attribute usage, or element usage](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/d108dfe17652d3f6a18bf76d0b7f955b74244998/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticExtension.cs)

For example, try this:

```
<Picker>
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:Static Member="local:SomeClass.ConstText" />
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```